# How does iterating over 3 elements at the same time using a combination of zip, * and *3 work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iterator

I'm trying to iterate over 3 elements at a time using the following (which seems to work):

```
for a, b, c in zip(*[iter(accounts_iter)]*3):
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
```

1. `accounts_iter` is a list of tuples I created.
2. `iter(accounts_iter)` unpacks `accounts_iter` into a list iterator, so its still a list of tuples just that its now iterable

Here's where I struggle to understand.

- `*[iter(accounts_iter)]` unpacks the list in `Step 2` into separate tuples, so no longer a list of tuples but individual tuples
- `*[iter(accounts_iter)]*3` multiplies that by 3

In my output, I do not seem to have duplicates, but am indeed able to process 3 items each loop.

But won't I have 3 copies of the same tuple once `zip(*[iter(accounts_iter)]*3)` happens?